# multiple level of implementing an interface for children classes

Tags: c#

In SocialAuth.Net lib (and some other libraries), I see a class is implementing an interface and the other class is inheriting that class and also implements that interface again like:

```
class Provider: IProvider
```

and there is

```
class LinkedInWrapper : Provider, IProvider
```

I checked LinkedInWrapper doesn't have to implement any of IProvider class because it's already implemented in Provider class.

My question is why LinkedInWrapper is implementing the interface again?

Comment: In this case it is just a marker, so you can see the interfaces on the `LinkedInWrapper` without looking up the `Provider` class. This is kind of an anti pattern but not uncommon. However in other cases you might want to reimplement interfaces.Eric Lippert [wrote an article about that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/12/08/so-many-interfaces-part-two/)

Comment: @Frank J do you happen to know the name of the anti-pattern?

Comment: Sorry, no not really, I just considered it as an an anti pattern, because what happens if the base class implements an additional interface, now you would have to go through all classes which inherit from the base class and update also their signature and do that for all levels. Seems not very productive. That is the same reason why C# doesn't have the `throws Exception` markers on functions, because something might change upstream and either now you have an inconsistency or a lot of work on your hands.

Comment: @FrankJ: Move your comment into an answer please.

Comment: @QualityCatalyst: I figured I wasn't elaborate enough for a complete answer, hence the comment only. I moved it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case it is just a marker, so you can see the interfaces on the `LinkedInWrapper` without looking up the `Provider` class.

This is kind of an anti pattern but not uncommon. I would consider this an anti-pattern because what happens if the base class implements an additional interface later?

Now you would have to go through all classes which inherit from the base class and update also their signature and do that for all levels, or have inconsistencies in your pattern. If the class is in a library, other people that use the library will guaranteed have initially inconsistencies because you can't change their code, even if they want to follow that pattern.

However, in other cases you might want to reimplement interfaces. Eric Lippert [wrote an article about that](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/12/08/so-many-interfaces-part-two/).